# Is it possible to add an option to the top of a select2 when data comes from ajax?

Tags: jquery-select2-4

I need to insert at the beginning of the list a new option in the select2 control.

I tried with

```
        var data = {
            id: -1,
            text: 'SISTEMA'
        };

        var newOption = new Option(data.text, data.id, false, false);
        $('#UsuarioId').append(newOption).trigger('change');
```

But that does not work when data comes from Ajax. In that case, the combobox appears with that option selected and when list is expanded, that option is not there.

Regards
Jaime

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable and initially define that variable as the option you want to include - eg:

```
var trHTML;    
trHTML = '<option value=""></option>'
```

Then loop through your result set adding each item back to that variable

```
$.each(x, function (i, item) {
      trHTML += '<option value=' + value_name +'>'+ display_name +'</option>';
});
```

Then append the entire list to the select, and initiate Select2

```
$('#dropdown_name').append(trHTML);
$('#dropdown_name').select2({
     placeholder: "foobar",
     allowClear: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This documentation from select2 already explains

https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax